# How can I use a subquery on my query results and then ORDER BY a calculated result for each row?

Tags: mysql, sql

## Context

I'm having some trouble putting together the logic of subqueries(?) together in my head.

```
   *---------*---------*---------*------------*------------*---------*
   |GUEST_ID | Country | County  | Attending  | Donation   | Party   |
   *---------*---------*---------*------------*------------*---------*
```

I have a database containing records about attendees of an charity ball.

**GUEST_ID**: Table key. 
**Country**: Country the guest is from. 
**County**: County the guest is from (i.e. a region within that country). 
**Attending**: Whether or not the guest is attending (i.e. true or false). 
**Donation**: Amount the guest is donating to the cause. 
**Party**: Which Party the guest is attending.

## Goal

I wish to display a table broken down by Country and County, showing the number of attendees from each Country + County, and the average donation of those who are attending from that Country + Country. I'd then like to order the rows from highest average donation to lowest. I understand the constituent parts of this query, however I'm not sure how to 'glue' it together as a whole.

I can `GROUP BY Country, County`.

I can `SUM(Donation)`.

I can `COUNT(*) WHERE ATTENDING = 'Yes'`

And I know I can `SET @variables` to store results in the interim.

I also know I can `ORDER BY DESC`. 




## So far

My issue is with understanding how to combine these elements into a functioning query. I'm guessing I need to use subqueries however it's getting the order right I'm having trouble with. This is what I have so far -

```
SELECT SUM(`Donation`) AS `TotalDonations`, `Country`, `County`  
FROM `GuestList` 
WHERE `Party` = `2014CharityBall`
GROUP BY `Country`, `County`
```

I'm not sure how to add the subquery to find the `COUNT` of only those guests who are definitely attending, or how to calculate the TotalDonations / DefinitelyAttending and then `ORDER BY` this.

## Results Required

```
*------------*------------*---------------*---------------*---------------*
| Country    | County     | # of Attendees|Total Donations|Avg. Donation  |
*------------*------------*---------------*---------------*---------------*
```

**Country**: Country the guests are from. 
**County**: County the guests are from (i.e. a region within that country). 
 
**# of Attendees**: Number of attendees (Attending = 'true') within that country and county. 
**Total Donations**: Total donations of all those attending (Attending = 'true') within that country and county (e.g. `SUM(Donation)`). 
**Avg. Donation**: Average donation of all those attending (Attending = 'true') within that country and county (e.g. `AVG(Donation)` - that is, ofc, Total Donations / # of Attendees).

## Extra Credit

*Just an expression ;)*

If I want to calculate the Total Donations *among all donators invited to the party*, and, separately, the Total Donations *solely among those donators attending the party*, how would I do that?

Comment: Yes, apologies. I'm still very new. I will add the correct tag. Thank you.

Comment: Just to poke, do you also need the gross total per country in the same resultset?

Comment: @Serpiton I have added the Results Required to my question

Comment: Perfect, but my previous asked something different: do you also need a total per country regadless of county?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, my mistake. No I don't need per country :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT `Country`, 
    `County`,
    SUM(`Donation`) AS `TotalDonations`,
    FORMAT(AVG(`Donation`), 0) AS `AVGDonations`,
    COUNT(1) Attending
    FROM `GuestList` 
    WHERE `Party` = `2014CharityBall`
           AND Attending = `Yes`
    GROUP BY `Country`, `County`
    Order by 4 desc
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. What is `ORDER BY 4`, please? What does the `4` refer to`?

Comment: This will return the `SUM` and `AVG` of everyone, not only the attending

Comment: @Eilidh, the 4th column in the SELECT statement.

Comment: @Serpiton, the GROUP BY should make it do the aggregate values at the group level.

Comment: This will shows the `AVGDonations` column as a float with three decimal places. How can I remove the decimal places?

Comment: 4 refers to the fourth column (of the result set). I don't like this convention.

Comment: @JBrooks I'd suggest maybe editing your posts so its `ORDER BY Guests DESC` rather than `ORDER BY 4 DESC`? It seems more readable imo?

Comment: @JBrooks Also, is there a way I can not display the Attending column?

Comment: @Eilidh Sure, just delete that row.

Comment: As @Serpiton says this doesn't only `SUM` and `AVG` the donations only of those attending. 

It does do this *per country + county*, as you say, with `GROUP BY`, but it does not look at `Attending` when calculating these.

Comment: @JBrooks How do you mean delete that row? I need `SUM(CASE WHEN Attending = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE)` so that the `COUNT(1) Guests` can be done and I can have a `Guests` column.